# clustering VS supervised classification, in the case of very small database

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I'm trying to classify/cluster subjects according to 4 features in two classes: healthy and sick.

Two things to know: I know the labels/classes of each subject + **I only have 40 subjects** (in total: training + testing set!)

**What should I choose in this case, clustering or classification?**

Comment: Classification, it's clearly a supervised problem. If sample size is an issue, consider doing statistical tests on the full data set (e.g. with logistic regression) rather than using a training and test set.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with logistic regression, can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: I can't go into much detail, that's for you to research. But in a nutshell, logistic regression will try to model the probability of health/sickness via a linear sum of your 4 features. Because it's a statistical model, instead of gauging accuracy with a test set, you could instead do hypothesis tests or get confidence intervals for the coefficients in the linear sum using statistical software. In Python for instance you can use this: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have labels, it's classification.

Clustering would be unsupervised. You can't ask it to classify into healthy and sick, it *may* find a very different partitioning of your data of that provides more structure.